# Delphi 11.3 FMX.TWebBrowser loop while trying to send consent confirmation for google Maps (Android)

Tags: android, delphi, redirect, twebbrowser

so right now i have a FMX App with a TWebBrowser set to EdgeIfAvailable and am trying to visit https://www.google.de/maps. If it's my first time visiting google maps i'm redirected to the consent page - so far so good - the problem occurs if i try to accept or decline the cookies on Android because i end up in a loop where the consent page is reloaded over and over again.
Im not trying to open google maps in the Maps App btw. I want the Browser version in my TWebBrowser.

Some threads here say i could use the "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" for this problem but it's seems wrong.The following is the standard implementation

```
function TAndroidWebBrowserService.TWebBrowserListener.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: JWebView; url: JString): Boolean;
begin
  FWBService.ShouldStartLoading(JStringToString(url));
  Result := False;
end;
```

At the moment my only work around is:

1. try visiting google maps
2. accepting or declining(entering the loop)
3. use a Button in the App that lets me navigate to another URL from google maps (with some random address)
4. now i can enter google maps and the normal url is okay again

I guess that the work around works because the cookie is set properly and only the redirect has an error

Is there perhaps a problem with the http code 302 or 303 in Android TWebBrowser or is it the Android Web View?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does it ask for consent only if you're in the EU or something? I ask because it does not show any consent here, so it might be a challenge to replicate and find a solution

Comment: yeah probably - at least i'm in the EU and every website needs to ask for consent to save cookies